# Is over riding .thumbnails{marging-left:20px} with 0px the same as unchecking it in Firebug?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, grid

Here is the link: http://unlockinglg.com/beta/index.html

Basically I want my thumbnails to align with the rest of the content above.

Right now it is skewed to the left.

See video of what I mean by unchecking .thumbnails{marging-left:20px}  http://screencast.com/t/4xCmVzWxfr.

I tried over-riding it by .thumbnails{marging-left:0px} but that didn't work.

Thanks

Comment: Remove `raw` class from wrapping `div`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in firebug, there is another rule that sets the `margin-left` property. By uncheking a rule, you don't set it to 0, you ignore it (so it looks for other applicable rules).

It may work with `margin-left: inherit;` and it should work with  `margin-left: 25px;`

But this is not the real problem : `.thumbnails` behave like a `.row` so it shouldn't be directly contained in one.

To make it simple, **try removing the `.row` wrapper**.

```html
<div class="marketing">
    <div class="row">
        <!-- ... -->
    </div>
    <hr>
    <!-- no .row -->
        <ul class="thumbnails steps">
            <li class="span4">
                <!-- ... -->
            </li>
        </ul>
    <!-- no /.row -->
</div>
```